# Clicking the "x new answer(s)" button on multi-page questions pushes down the pagination buttons

Tags: bug, design, pagination

If a new answer is posted to a multi-page question, and you click the "x new answer(s)" button, this happens:

> [image]

I initially observed this over on MSO on the question asking for suggestions for the 2020 developer survey, but the screenshot is from a test in the sandbox. I managed to trigger it thanks to the connection staying alive even though my computer was off, but it looked like this:

> [image]

Again with the pagination controlls pushed down.

Refreshing clears the order of the answers, and none of the answers are above the controlls like that afterwards, but this doesn't seem like the expected behavior.